# Why does the objects reset after invalidation of an NSTimer?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, nstimer

I have a `NSTimer` that calls a function that moves some `UIImageView`'s, when I invalidate the `NSTimer` I thought the `UIImageView`'s would stop in their locations, but they reset to the location set by the `StoryBoard`.

Is there something I do wrong or not including or is this a mysterium?

EDIT - added some code

.h

```
NSTimer *updater;
```

.m

```
updater = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f/32.0f target:self selector:@selector(gameEngine) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


-(void)gameEngine {
    //move some images around
}

-(IBAction)action {
    [updater invalidate];
}
```

Comment: Could you show us some code ?

Comment: its very little I dont think its very necessery but ok.

Comment: I suspect that the moving of the controls back to their original location is unrelated to the timer, but rather by the use of auto layout and the constraints being reapplied. Are you using auto layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using auto layout, when the constraints are re-applied (which can be triggered by innocuous events, such as setting the `text` property of a label), everything will be placed back to where they were defined by the constraints embedded in the storyboard (assuming you were attempting to move the `UIImageView` objects programmatically simply by changing their `frame` or `center` properties rather than by changing the constraints).

You can solve this in one of two ways.

1. Move your `UIImageView` objects by changing the `constant` property for the constraint and then calling `layoutIfNeeded` method of the parent view, rather than changing the `frame` or `center` properties of the `UIImageView` itself. This can be simplified if, in Interface Builder, you create `IBOutlet` references for the constraints themselves.
2. Turn off auto auto layout and then you can use the `frame` or `center` properties as I suspect you currently are. You can turn off auto layout by opening up your storyboard, clicking on the first tab in the rightmost panel, and unchecking "Use Autolayout":

   [image]

The first approach is a little more cumbersome and while the second approach may seem easier, auto layout is the future of iOS development, and it might be worthwhile to master the moving of controls via constraints.

Comment: That did the trick, I realy hate the new screensize of iPhone 5... makes it a pain in the a** to develop things now.